# If hasClass condition jquery not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to execute some alerts with some onclick events and conditions with jquery statement. But it seems that event handlers don't work properly, probably due the fact that is missing something in my event handling logic. I have just 1 button, with id #`bottone1`, and I have some menu buttons with id `#b1` and #`b2`.

The first event works fine, it adds correctly the class "`cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady`". When i click on `#bottone1` it starts the the first alert "`cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady`". Also the `onClick` event `$("#b1")` works properly, it removes the class "`cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady`" and replaces with the class "`cliccatoInvoca1`".

#### This point i encounter the first problem

When i click on `#bottone1` it comes like first alert "`cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady`", and then "cliccatoInvoca1". Then when i click on `#b2` and afer that i click on `#bottone1` it executes 3 alerts, "`cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady`", "`cliccatoInvoca1`" and finally "`cliccatoInvoca3`".

So, the main problem is that it doesn't work if condition for execute only 1 alert at time. So when i click on #`bottone1` it executes all the alerts in sequence.

#### This is my document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select-1").multiselect();
    invoca1();
    $("#bottone1").addClass("cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady btn btn-default");
    if ($("#bottone1").hasClass("cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady")) {
        $("#bottone1").click(function () {
            alert("cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady");
            keys = [];
            $('input[name="multiselect_select-1"]:checked').each(function () {
                keys.push(this.value);
            });
        });
    }

    $("#b1").click(function () {
        invoca1();
        $("#bottone1").removeClass("cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady noClass").addClass("cliccatoInvoca1");
        if ($("#bottone1").hasClass("cliccatoInvoca1")) {
            $("#bottone1").click(function () {
                alert("cliccatoInvoca1");
                keys = [];
                $('input[name="multiselect_select-1"]:checked').each(function () {
                    keys.push(this.value);
                });
            });
        }
    });

    $("#b2").click(function () {
        invoca3();
        $("#bottone1").removeClass("cliccatoInvoca1").addClass("cliccatoInvoca3");
        if ($("#bottone1").hasClass("cliccatoInvoca3")) {
            $("#bottone1").click(function () {
                alert("cliccatoInvoca3");
                keys = [];
                $('input[name="multiselect_select-1"]:checked').each(function () {
                    keys.push(this.value);
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You are wiring up click events inside click events. That is almost always a sign of problems as you never disconnect the previous event handlers!

Comment: Yes, and besides, you always call hasClass after you've added the same class. What's the point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to use delegated event handlers, attached to a non-changing ancestor element, each with a matching selector:

e.g. like this:

```
$(document).on('click', "#bottone1.cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady", function() {
    alert("cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady");
    keys = [];
    $('input[name="multiselect_select-1"]:checked').each(function () {
         keys.push(this.value);
    });
});
```

The above is now all you need for one click handler, repeat the pattern for the other classes it can have. You never need the `hasClass` checks.

Your other code just becomes simple like this:

```
$("#b1").click(function () {
     invoca1();
     $("#bottone1").removeClass("cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady noClass").addClass("cliccatoInvoca1");
 });
```

### Delegated handlers:

- Delegated event handlers work by listening for the event (in this case `click`) to  bubble up to the ancestor element.
- You normally choose the closest non-changing ancestor element, but `document` is the default if nothing else is closer/convenient. Do not use `'body'` as it has a bug related to styling that can cause mouse events not to bubble to it.
- *Then* it applies the jQuery selector to only the elements in the bubble-chain.
- It *then* applies the function, only to the matching elements *that caused the event*.
- The result is the elements only need to match at *event time* and not *event registration* time.

This pattern will simplify your code significantly.

The entire example will become something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select-1").multiselect();
    invoca1();
    $("#bottone1").addClass("cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady btn btn-default");

    $("#b1").click(function () {
        invoca1();
        $("#bottone1").removeClass("cliccatoInvoca1_OnReady noClass").addClass("cliccatoInvoca1");
    });

    $("#b2").click(function () {
        invoca3();
        $("#bottone1").removeClass("cliccatoInvoca1").addClass("cliccatoInvoca3");
    });

    $(document).on('click', "#bottone1.cliccatoInvoca1", function () {
        alert("cliccatoInvoca1");
        keys = [];
        $('input[name="multiselect_select-1"]:checked').each(function () {
            keys.push(this.value);
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', "#bottone1.cliccatoInvoca3", function () {
        alert("cliccatoInvoca3");
        keys = [];
        $('input[name="multiselect_select-1"]:checked').each(function () {
            keys.push(this.value);
        });
    });
});
```

### Notes:

- I am ignoring the fact that your event handlers contain identical code and assume the real code has different operations.